# MONAI Transform stuck converting 4D NIfTI volumes for 3D multichannel network

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, medical-imaging

I am building off of MONAI's [3D segmentation tutorial](https://github.com/Project-MONAI/tutorials/blob/main/3d_segmentation/challenge_baseline/run_net.py) to work with 4D `NIfTI` data, where the fourth dimension represents the channels to be inputted for the proposed 3D network. I have adapted the tutorial to better segment with `MONAI's DynUNet(nnUNet)`, but am facing trouble correctly transforming the data into the desired format to train my 3D network in multichannel.

My current approach seems to cause the previously-working DynUNet to get stuck while loading data (estimated time 12+ hrs to load and was Killed by server, was ~1 min previously). I am unable to find if I am transforming/preparing the data correctly for 3D multichannel training.

The current input dimension looks like `[num_px_x, num_px,y, num_slices, num_channels]`, and I hope to transform it into a 3D volume able to be used for a multichannel network.
If helpful, the 4th dimension is of length 7, where index 0 represents an intensity value and indices 1-6 represent a one-hot encoded sequence.

A snippet of my function to get transform:

```
def get_xforms(mode="train", keys=("image", "label")):
    """returns a composed transform for train/val/infer."""

    xforms = [
        LoadImaged(keys),
        EnsureChannelFirstd(keys='image'),

        AsChannelFirstd(keys),

        Orientationd(keys, axcodes="LPS"),
    ]
    return monai.transforms.Compose(xforms)
```

Training data loader

```py
# format: [ {'image': 'ct file path', 'label': 'seg file path'} ]
train_files = [{keys[0]: img, keys[1]: seg} for img, seg in zip(images[:n_train], labels[:n_train])]
val_files = [{keys[0]: img, keys[1]: seg} for img, seg in zip(images[-n_val:], labels[-n_val:])]

keys = ("image", "label")
batch_size = 2

train_transforms = get_xforms("train", keys)
train_ds = monai.data.CacheDataset(data=train_files, transform=train_transforms)
train_loader = monai.data.DataLoader(
    train_ds,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=2,
    pin_memory=torch.cuda.is_available(),
)
```

Network function

```py
def get_net():
    kernels=[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
    strides=[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]

    num_classes = 2
    net = monai.networks.nets.DynUNet(
        spatial_dims=3,
        in_channels=7,
        out_channels=num_classes,
        kernel_size=kernels,
        strides=strides,
        upsample_kernel_size=strides[1:],
    )

    return net
```

Other code segments are mostly consistent with MONAI's [tutorial](https://github.com/Project-MONAI/tutorials/blob/main/3d_segmentation/challenge_baseline/run_net.py)

Answer (score 0):

I used multichannel training with 3D U-Net.

```
data_dicts = [
    {"image": image_name, "label": label_name, "seg": seg_name}
    for image_name, label_name, seg_name in zip(X_train, y_train, X_segs)
]
```

I had channels `image` and `seg` which I added with `ConcatItemsd`

```
train_transforms = Compose(
[
    LoadImaged(keys=["image", "label", "seg"]),
    EnsureChannelFirstd(keys=["image", "label", "seg"]),
    ConcatItemsd(keys=["image", "seg"], name="img"),        
    CropForegroundd(keys=["img", "label"], source_key="img"),
    RandCropByPosNegLabeld(
        keys=["img", "label"],
        label_key="label",
        spatial_size=(192,192,64),
        pos=1,
        neg=1,
        num_samples=4,
        image_key="img",
        image_threshold=0,
    ),
    EnsureTyped(keys=["img", "label"]),
]
```

An example of such data is of dimension `[batch_size, num_of_channels, size_x, size_y, size_z]`. So I think that your dimensions are wrong. The number of channels should be before the spatial size of a current window.